# Did Ada83 or Ada95 define a memory model to support multitasking?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, ada, memory-model

With the "recent" changes to C and C++ adding memory models (similar to Java and C#), I was wondering whether Ada83 or Ada95 inbuilt support for concurrency also defined a memory model.

Does anybody know of any references about whether Ada defined a memory model?

Bonus question: was Ada83 the first general programming language to offer INBUILT support for shared-state concurrency?

Answer (score 5):

I think the nearest to a memory model in the sense you're asking about is the [Dynamic Semantics](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-C-6.html#p15) section of the ARM.

Ada 83 had [pragma Shared](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-09-11.html).

Ada 95 [replaced this](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95lrm/ARM_HTML/RM-C-6.html) with pragmas Atomic, Volatile, Atomic_Components, and Volatile_Components; Ada 2005 was the same with (in a Correction) pragmas Independent and Independent_Components (that is, the referenced object, or each of its components, is independently addressable).

Ada 2012 replaces the pragmas with [aspects](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-C-6.html), for good but not immediately relevant reasons:

```
Imported_Variable : Integer with
  Import, Convention => C, External_Name => "exported_variable", Volatile;
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Tasking & Shared memory, I think you should be looking at [Protected Types](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Tasking#Protected_types). For concurrency this allows different threads (tasks) to share a resource without the need for explicit mutexes.